# Differences in reading bits from byte pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm finding it difficult to understand the differences between the below code:

```
    auto pixel = static_cast<uint32_t>( D3DCOLOR_RGBA( r, g, b, a ) );
    auto components = (uint8_t*)&pixel;
    std::array<uint8_t, 4> pixel_colours = { components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3] };

    uint8_t b_a = pixel >> 24;
    uint8_t b_r = ( pixel >> 16 ) & 0xFF;
    uint8_t b_g = ( pixel >> 8 ) & 0xFF;
    uint8_t b_b = pixel & 0xFF;

    return static_cast<uint32_t>( D3DCOLOR_RGBA( r, g, b, a ) );
```

For r, g, b, a = { 255, 128, 64, 0 }, the value for pixel_colours is `{ 64, 128, 255, 0}` while b_a, b_r, b_g, b_b are `0, 255, 128, 64`

I don't understand why the differences are occurring - I expect them to be the same. Could someone explain?

Comment: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Atomic_element_size_8-bit_2)

Comment: If pixel is RGBA, shouldn't it be `b_r = pixel >> 24` ... `b_a = pixel & 0xFF`? Looks like the second example is ARGB.

Comment: Also modify your test to `{255, 128, 64, 0}` so you can see better. Now you cannot distinguish between 255 and 255.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Change made, ah, Endians..... If you would write an answer, I shall mark this checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`components[0]` ... `components[1]` access the memory as a byte array and read in the order laid out in memory. `pixel >> 24` ... `pixel & 0xFF` access the logical value of the int. Since x86 and x64 (Intel) architecture uses Little Endian, the two differ. The Wiki article on [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Atomic_element_size_8-bit_2) explains all the details.